# Phonegap Plugins work on CLI?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Does the Phonegap Plugins work on CLI or only on the phonegap online build?
If yes, please tell me how to properly integrate the splashscreen plugin on phonegap 3.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plugins work locally, not just in PhoneGap Build.

To install a new plugin (such as the Splashscreen plugin) run:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

Implementation works the same as PhoneGap Build — see the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html).

Comment: I added the plugin but it's not showing the splashscreen... What else should I add? I also added:     <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" /> o my config.xml file

Comment: do I need to add something else?

Comment: @user3284623 For Android, add `<feature name="SplashScreen"><param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen" /></feature>` to config.xml. For iOS, add `<feature name="SplashScreen"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" /></feature>`.

Answer (score 0):

From Cordova 3.3 the right call is as follows:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Keep in mind to use cordova cli not phonegap, phonegap uses cordova but its focus is on the phonegap build, however it still allows you to do local stuff without the build.

Comment: if I use phonegap for CLI and after the app is complete I use phonegap online build to build it for all platforms (also for ios because I dont have a MAC) will the results be the same?

Comment: should be, as the build uses the same plugin. splashscreen is part of the default plugin list for cordova.